# Perl If/Else Optimization

Tags: perl, if-statement, optimization

Suppose I have a string `$a = "abc";`

In terms of optimization and speed, would it be faster if I ran

```
if ($a ne "abc") {
    print "Not abc";
} else {
    print "abc";
}
```

Versus

```
if ($a eq "abc") {
    print "abc";
} else {
    print "Not abc";
}
```

? I am asking  because I have a loop that will typically enter the `else` statement and I wanted to know if I could make it run more efficiently by switching the if/else clauses

Comment: You shouldn't try to optimise your code until you have a working program and found it to be too slow. In any case there are many other places to look that are far more likely to reward you with improved speed than switching the `if` and the `else` clauses of a conditional statement

Comment: If this micro-optimization speeds up your program in any meaningful way, you don't have enough real problems to solve.

Comment: I was surprised when I benchmarked this and saw a significant (relative) difference. `$a = "abc"; if ($a eq "abc") ...` and `$a = "not abc"; if ($a ne "abc") ...` were both ~100% faster than the alternatives (on my machine, with my possibly flawed benchmark). This is interesting, but when you consider that even the slower of the two executes more than *11 million times per second*, it should become obvious that it's a waste of your time to optimize this. The key to optimization is optimizing bottlenecks; this will not be the bottleneck for any real program.

Comment: `$a` and `$b` are reserved for use in `sort` blocks. Don't use them for other stuff.

Comment: And as even more evidence of why you shouldn't bother: my previous benchmark had no-ops in the `if` and `else` blocks; I ran a new benchmark that actually did something, and the results were reversed (and the differences much less pronounced).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: What do you mean no-ops?

Comment: @Bijan `1;`, which does nothing and in this particular case is optimized away entirely from the `if` block (although not the `else` block, apparently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are typically going to go to the else block in the first example, then yes, the second example would be a little bit faster. However, when I say a little bit, I mean a very small amount of optimization that you probably won't notice unless you are running the code millions of times.